# NAT translation ceases working after couple hours

Tags: cisco, nat

I have a CISCO 1941 with 2 external IP addresses assigned to one interface

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description $ETH-WAN$
 ip address X.X.X.X2 255.255.255.240 secondary
 ip address X.X.X.X1 255.255.255.240
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
```

I have various port translations on the primary IP. The secondary IP statically translates to a server with IP 192.168.19.17. This works fine for a couple hours and then ceases working.
Issuing the following fixes the problem:

```
router(config)#no ip nat inside source static 192.168.129.17 X.X.X.X2
router(config)#ip nat inside source static 192.168.129.17 X.X.X.X2
```

Any idea? When it stops working, issuing traceroute X.X.X.X2 stops at X.X.X.X1

Is it something wrong with my configuration (see below)?

How can I debug it?

```
router#sh run
(...)
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description $ETH-LAN$
 ip address 192.168.129.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no mop enabled
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description $ETH-WAN$
 ip address X.X.X.X2 255.255.255.240 secondary
 ip address X.X.X.X1 255.255.255.240
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Virtual-Template1 type tunnel
 ip unnumbered GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip mtu 1300
 tunnel mode ipsec ipv4
 tunnel protection ipsec profile CiscoCP_Profile1
!
ip local pool SDM_POOL_1 192.168.129.200 192.168.129.254
ip forward-protocol nd
!
ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip dns server
ip nat inside source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/1 overload
ip nat inside source route-map SDM_RMAP_1 interface GigabitEthernet0/1 overload
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.129.13 500 X.X.X.X1 500 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.129.13 500 X.X.X.X1 500 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.129.13 548 X.X.X.X1 548 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.129.13 548 X.X.X.X1 548 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.129.13 1701 X.X.X.X1 1701 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.129.13 1701 X.X.X.X1 1701 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.129.13 1723 X.X.X.X1 1723 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.129.13 1723 X.X.X.X1 1723 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.129.13 3283 X.X.X.X1 3283 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.129.13 3283 X.X.X.X1 3283 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.129.22 3389 X.X.X.X1 3389 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.129.13 4500 X.X.X.X1 4500 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.129.13 4500 X.X.X.X1 4500 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.129.13 5900 X.X.X.X1 5900 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.129.13 5900 X.X.X.X1 5900 extendable
ip nat inside source static 192.168.129.17 X.X.X.X2
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 X.X.X.gateway 254
ip route 172.17.0.0 255.255.0.0 192.168.129.9
!
access-list 1 permit 192.168.129.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 1 permit 46.182.204.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.128.0 0.0.15.255 any
access-list 100 permit ip 172.17.0.0 0.0.0.255 any
access-list 101 remark CCP_ACL Category=4
access-list 101 remark IPSec Rule
access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.129.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.130.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 102 remark CCP_ACL Category=2
access-list 102 permit ip 192.168.129.0 0.0.0.255 any
!
!
!
!
route-map SDM_RMAP_1 permit 1
 match ip address 102
!
(...)
```

Comment: May be related to a full nat translation table, can you check the number of active translations?

Comment: Is there a reason that you're overloading the X.X.X.2 by using it as a secondary interface IP on the outside?

Comment: @marctxk i guess there isn't but i'm not really sure how to do otherwise

Comment: What is the IOS version, and can you get "show ip nat trans" when the problem occurs? Also, is there anything in the logs?

Comment: You might be running up against a memory/capacity issue.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have no reasons to use secondary IP of X.X.X.X2 rather than as a natted IP for 192.168.129.17 (192.168.129.17 -> X.X.X.X2), then you don't need to configure it as secondary IP on WAN interface (G0/1).

As long as there is a free public IP reserved for your network (here is .X2), you can use it directly in your NAT statement without needing it to be "up" and "pingable" at first.

In other words, the following configuration is enough for 192.168.129.17 to be natted to .X2 when accessing the Internet.

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description $ETH-WAN$
  ip address X.X.X.X1 255.255.255.240
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto

ip nat inside source static 192.168.129.17 X.X.X.X2
```

2. One thing I noticed is that the iP of 192.168.129.17 is in subnet 192.168.129.0/24 covered in access-list 1 and 102, and this subnet is natted to G0/1 (IP of .X1), while you want the IP 192.168.129.17 to be natted to IP .X2. And this It would cause confusion.

You can redesign your ACLs and explicitly exclude IP 192.168.129.17 to be involved in NAT statement to .X1.

3. To debug your NAT packets, simply apply "debug ip nat" command on global mode.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, I'm pretty new to Cisco. I understand it but when I removed X2 from the interface I could ping it but not access it (http or ssh). I did not fix the ACLs though. Should both be fixed? Should it be something like: `access-list 1 deny 192.168.129.17` and `access-list 102 deny ip 192.168.129.17 any`. I'll try that later. (I must do it at night...).

Comment: May I know what subnet of 46.182.204.0/24 and why it in access-list 1?

Comment: I would like to keep access-list 1 (in case I am clear of what subnet 46.182.204.0/24 is used for) or 102 and remove the other. Because both of them are used for NAT (based on the configuration you uploaded and if they aren't used somewhere else).

Comment: It doesn't work to remove the secondary IP from my configuration. could it be because I have other routers on the same internet output?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a memory / memory leak issue. See [Verifying NAT Operation and Basic NAT Troubleshooting](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/network-address-translation-nat/8605-13.html)

> The %NAT: System busy. Try later error message appears when a show
>   command related to NAT or a show running-config or write memory
>   command is executed. This issue is due to the increase in the size of
>   the NAT table. When the size of the NAT table increases, the router
>   runs out of memory.
>
> Reload the router in order to solve this issue. If the error message
>   appears when HSRP SNAT is configured, configure these commands in
>   order to resolve the issue:
>
> ```
> Router(config)#standby delay minimum 20 reload 20
> Router(config)#standby 2 preempt delay minimum 20 reload 20 sync 10
> ```